# How to figure out caller of the nesting function in Python

Tags: python, function, testing

My program communicates with the networking equipment using Telnet and SNMP. Telnet and SNMP have different commands for the same functionality, for example clearing the configuration of the device. I need to abstract my test logic from the actual device, so I use hardware abstraction layer like this:

```
#ClearConfigCommand is an interface I use in my tests
def ClearCongifCommand(type = 'cli')
    if type == 'cli':
        return 'clear config'
    elif type == 'snmp':
        return 'oid and some more information'
```

In my program I send commands using SNMP and Telnet like this:

```
#Create connection to the device
cTelnet = Telnet('192.168.1.2')
cTelnet.Send(ClearConfigCommand())
cSNMP = SNMP('192.168.1.2')
cSNMP.Send(ClearConfigCommand('snmp'))
```

Is it possible for ClearConfigCommand() to know what type of the connection I'm using so I don't need to pass 'snmp' parameter to it? The code I'd like to have is something like:

```
#Create connection to the device
cTelnet = Telnet('192.168.1.2')
cSNMP = SNMP('192.168.1.2')
cTelnet.Send(ClearConfigCommand())
#We don't 
cSNMP.Send(ClearConfigCommand())
```

I tried to use stack but it doesn't work out because ClearConfigCommand() is invoked before Send(), so I can't tell what object (Telnet or SNMP) is using output of ClearConfigCommand().

Comment: No, a function call expression doesn't contain enough information to reliably know what is going to happen to the return value or the context in which it was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more classical approach would be wrap the `Telnet` and `SNMP` classes with your own classes providing a `ClearConfigCommand()`:

```
class MyTelnet(Telnet):
    def ClearConfigCommand(self):
        self.Send('clear config')

class MySNMP(SNMP):
    def ClearConfigCommand(self):
        self.Send('oid and some more information')

cTelnet = MyTelnet('192.168.1.2')
cTelnet.ClearConfigCommand()
etc...
```

That way, your classes have all the functionality of the original classes in addition to the functionality you are adding.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That was the first approach I tried. However, things become much more complicated with it. In fact, each of the Send() functions receive 3 argument 1) command that I would like to send (as explained above) 2) the reply I expect to receive (virtual output) and 3) pointer to the function that I use to compare real output and virtual output. So Send((1),(2),(3)) sends a command (1), receive a reply (error message, OK message, specific table etc) and compare it to what I expect (2) using function (3).

Comment: if you say, just don't see that this approach is inherently more complicated than the one you were proposing... in the end, either way, the same work has to be done.